# Primary Election Statistics: Query

Tags: feature-request, election

There is a [moderator election on Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/election) right now, and we are in the primary part of the election.

We were wondering whether it was possible to see the evolution of the votes as a function of time using a query like SEDE. Or are these data not available to users?

Comment: something like [2015 Election Live Vote Monitor](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290346/839601) discussed at MSO?

Comment: @gnat, this is a neat tool. One of us made a script to be run on the page of the election to get the current status. However I would like to make a timeline. As far as I can tell that Live Vote connects to the actuall page and reads the current values, but not the history of it (more than just a two points difference), or is it?

Comment: you better ask tool author (who posted that at MSO), I don't know much details

Comment: It retrieves it from the page. So no retrieving afterward.